# Notation for the sum of squares of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, e.g. $\mathbf a = \mathbf b = [1,2,3,4,5]$.

I want to notate $c = \sum_i \left( a_i^2 \cdot b_i^2 \right)$. What is the vector shorthand for this? Does $c = \mathbf{a}^2\cdot \mathbf{b}^2$ work?

Comment: No, since that is $(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)(b_1^2+\cdots+b_n^2)$.

Comment: The symbol $\mathbf{a}^2$ is meaningless to me.

Comment: Maybe  $\sum_{i=1}^{size(a)} a \cdot  \sum_{i=1}^{size(b)} b$?

Comment: @MPW $\mathbf a^2$ means the same as any of $\mathbf a\cdot \mathbf a, (\mathbf a, \mathbf a),  \langle \mathbf a \mid \mathbf a\rangle, \mathbf a^T\mathbf a$ and possibly a lot of others (pick your favourite).

Comment: You could write 
$$c=\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf a)^2\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b)^2),
$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf x)$ is the diagonal matrix with the entries of $\mathbf x$ on its diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Hadamard product or Hadamard power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) you could write that inner product as $\langle a\circ a,b\circ b\rangle=\langle a^{\circ2},b^{\circ2}\rangle$